# How to create a custom sbt task that sets java options before running the app

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to have a new sbt task `runDev` that is the equivalent of setting a system property first, then running `run`:

```
sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback-dev.xml" ; run'
```

How can I do this in sbt?

Answer (score 1):

```
lazy val runDev = taskKey[Unit]("Run with custom java options")

fork in runDev := true
javaOptions in runDev += "-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback-dev.xml"

fullRunTask(runDev, Compile, "mainClass")
```

Comment: i updated example. it prints a log msg with a current value of javaOptions. fork option is an important one - run will live in forked JVM with specified params.

Comment: Your new version also sets the option for plain `sbt run` -- I was looking for the option to be only added when running `sbt runDev`

Comment: sorry for that, check another version pls.

Comment: Nice! this seems to work. 'fork in task' was the key.

Comment: I'm afraid this latest version doesn't work either -- the system property isn't set when calling `sbt runDev`.

Comment: replace `mainClass` with full path to you main class.

Comment: @yusuk. That's not the problem: "the system property isn't set when calling sbt runDev". Can I ask if you've actually tried out your own solution?

Comment: sounds like it didn't work this time as well=) yes i did. can be that my tests are not accurate enough. can i ask you how do you do testing?

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
lazy val helloRun = inputKey[Unit]("Run as a task")

helloRun := {
            javacOptions += "-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback-dev.xml"
            (run in Compile).evaluated
         }
```

Comment: are javaOptions not being set or does the program not run or is there an error?

Comment: Ah, sorry -- yeah, the program runs, but that system property isn't set.

Comment: type! should have been javacOptions. try again pls.

Comment: Sadly `javacOptions` isn't going to help -- that sends options to the java compiler, not the JVM runtime